# Alternating rows background depending a changing value in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Here is a blade template of my table, where I have issues changing rows depending on a value. If the command number changes I want the row and all the following rows with that command number to change and then alternate between white/grey colors everytime it's a different one.

I know it looks pretty basic but I can't make the condition in my algorithm. My first if looks if the previous iteration has a different command number and change the class, but I'm missing the one checking if the previous iteration has the same command number so keep the same background. I don't know how to check something css class and alternate the 2 backgrounds white/grey. I tried with $attributes from Laravel but it is always undefined.
I hope I was clear with my issue, also the table is already sorted by increasing command_number.

If you need the controller I can provide it.

Thanks

```
 tr.second th, tr.second td {
            background-color: #D1D1D1;
        }
//////
<tbody>
                    @foreach($data as $key => $line)
                        @if($key > 0)
                            <tr @if ($data[$key]['command_number'] != $data[$key-1]['command_number']) class="second"
                                @elseif()
                                @endif>

                                @foreach($line as $item)
                                    @if(($item == $line['quantity']) || ($item == $line['delivery']))
                                        <td>
                                            <strong>{{$item}}</strong>
                                        </td>
                                    @elseif($item == $line['hours'])
                                        <td>
                                            <strong style="color: red;">{{$item}}</strong>
                                        </td>
                                    @else
                                        <td>
                                            {{$item}}
                                        </td>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

Comment: You should store the class name into a variable, and then “toggle” that variable, whenever the command number changes between one record and the next. And then you just output the value of that variable as the content of the class attribute (without applying any further conditions in that place.)

Comment: key is a unique key for the command?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, key represents the current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the class based on a previous result, why don't you track the css class to use with a toggle variable outside of the loop like so:

```
// in your blade file
@php
    $toggle = false;
@endphp

@foreach(range(0, 10) as $number)

    <div class="@if($toggle) someClass @else otherClass @endif unrelatedClasses">
        
    </div>

    @php 
        $toggle = !$toggle 
    @endphp 

@endforeach
```

**Alternatively, the toggle should function in your case:**

```
// You could change the value of toggle based on your use case, like:
@php 
    $toggle = ($data[$key]['command_number'] != $data[$key-1]['command_number']);
@endphp
```

Instead of using `$key`, you can also use `$loop->index` to get the current iteration.

**Loop variable for even/odd cases**

For other use cases, the `loop` variable has several properties and methods you can use (like `even`, `odd`). Check out the [Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable).

**CSS selector for even/odd cases**

There are also CSS solutions using selectors like: `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` for even and odd numbers respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I can continue with this new perspective. But key is not defined if I put your @php suggestion before the foreach. 
Do you mean to replace $toggle = false or $toggle = !$toggle by your second suggestion ?

Comment: You should replace the code: $toggle = !$toggle  with your own implementation. Which you have created in the provided example and I have used as my second suggestion.

If this answered your question, could you mark it as answered?

Comment: Thanks. I will mark it as answered if I manage to have the right behavior. For now I don't have the right alternating.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you run into any problems!

Answer (score -1):

```
<tbody>
               @php($currentKey = null)     
               @foreach($data as $key => $line)
                        @if($key > 0)
                            <tr @if ($data[$key]['command_number'] != $currentKey) class="second"
                                @elseif()
                                @endif>

                                @foreach($line as $item)
                                    @if(($item == $line['quantity']) || ($item == $line['delivery']))
                                        <td>
                                            <strong>{{$item}}</strong>
                                        </td>
                                    @elseif($item == $line['hours'])
                                        <td>
                                            <strong style="color: red;">{{$item}}</strong>
                                        </td>
                                    @else
                                        <td>
                                            {{$item}}
                                        </td>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    @php($currentKey = $data[$key]['command_number']) 
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```